# Batch Files: List all files in a directory, print as .txt and place output file in all sub directories

Tags: windows, list, batch-file, directory

**1.**

Searched everywhere, I do find tutorials to print list of files in directory and sub directories using dir command as follows:

```
@echo off
dir /S > list.txt
pause
```

Above code will return all files in list.txt. We can use switches to get lists in various formats.
What I am trying to do is:
When I run batch file output file list.txt should be placed in all Sub Directories and not only in the directory from batch file is being executed.

**2.**

I am trying to to rename list.txt as %current directory name%.txt and having no clues to achieve that.

Comment: Code provided by Squashman is working fine and printing print.txt in folder and subfolder. But when I tried to print bare format output through /b switch using following code : 
    ' del /b List.txt for /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /b') DO @echo "%%G">>"%%~dpGList.txt" ' It is not working.

Comment: @Squashman can you please address bare format output issue as mentioned above...

Answer (score 1):

This uses the for variable modifiers as the directory it needs to write the list.txt file.

```
del /s list.txt
for /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /b /s') DO @echo "%%G">>"%%~dpGlist.txt"
```

Comment: Yes, list.txt is now being printed and placed in each folder. Is it possible to rename list.txt to %current-folder-name%.txt?

Comment: @manaswin, would need to nest another `FOR` command to parse out the last folder name.  Again you would use the command modifiers to do this.

Comment: @Squashman, Can you (or any gentleman here) please show the code as example 2 please...
Or someone may throw another piece of code entirely to print foldername.txt in each subfolder.

Comment: @manaswin, that is unfortunately a bit harder to code and I can't figure out a clean way to do it.

Comment: I have tried to print bare format output through /b switch. Code uses is as follows : 
    del /b List.txt for /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /b') DO @echo "%%G">>"%%~dpGList.txt" 

But it is not working. However with /b /s switch it is working fine.