# Windows 10 Command Line nested for over directory contents

Tags: loops, batch-file, directory

I'm trying to loop over all sub-directories in a directory and echo its name to a text file, then for each file in each of these sub-directories echo the filename and extension to the same text file. So far I have the following in my .bat file:

```
@echo off
for /D %%d in (*) do (echo %%d >> test.txt
 for /r %%i in (%%d) do echo %%~nxi >> test.txt)
```

Individually

```
for /D %%d in (*) do (echo %%d >> test.txt
```

and

```
for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%~nxi >> test.txt)
```

work to output the names of the sub-directories or files in *, but when I combine them I just get the names of the sub-directories repeated a bunch of times in the text file.

What am I doing wrong in this nested loop? How do I fix it to output what I need?

Example of required output:

```
Directory1
File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt
Directory2
Filex.jpg
Filey.jpg
```

Comment: Why not just use `tree`?

Comment: The ultimate aim of this is to generate code for me. The directory I'm working with has several folders, each with lots of images. I want to use the script to generate code to build an object containing all the files instead of having to capture all the information manually.

Comment: Answered a similar question a few weeks ago. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40225913/1417694

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is one level of depth, then don't use `for /r`.  That recurses.  Instead, do this:

```js
@echo off & setlocal

>test.txt (
    for /d %%D in (*) do (
        echo %%~D
        for %%I in ("%%~D\*") do echo %%~nxI
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems I was just missing how to set the "in" properly for the inner loop.